# Incentive compatibilty conditions for multi-item auctions

Tags: reference-request, auctions, mechanism-design, incentives

In [this](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~parkes/cs286r/spring07/papers/myerson.pdf) paper by Myerson on optimal single item auctions, the incentive compatibility condition is shown to be equivalent to the following simpler conditions on the auction - (i) the allocation probability being monotonic in bid (ii) the form of the payment rule.

Is there a similar characterization for multi-item auctions? Any reference regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is essentially the same idea as with just one unit.
For example, see the text leading to Proposition 14.1 in the book "Auction Theory" by Vijay Krishna.

Let $x$ be the vector of willingness-to-pay.
Define $U(x) = \max_z \{ q(z)x - m(z)\}$ as the equilibrium utility of type $x$. The incentive compatibility (I am quoting Krishna now) "implies for all $x$,
the probability vector $q(x)$ is a subgradient of the payoff function $U$, which
is convex, at the point $x$. In other words, the vector $q(x)$ is perpendicular to
the hyperplane that supports the function $U$ at $x$ — the graph of the function $U$
lies above the hyperplane." He goes on to show that
$$U(x) = U(0) + \int_0^1 q (t \cdot x) x d t,$$
where instead of directly integrating over the type $x$ you integrate  over $t\in (0,1)$.